# How do I combine multiple probability density functions into one ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm a complete R noob and I'm trying to combine multiple beta distributions into a single ggplot. Here is what I've got so far....

```
#to create a continuous probability function

x=seq(0,1,.01)
q=dbeta(x,2.2,1.7)
z=dbeta(x,3.3,1.2)
df=data.frame(x,q,z)
t=ggplot(df, aes(x)) +                       # basic graphical object
       geom_line(aes(y=q), colour="red") +   # first layer
       geom_line(aes(y=z), colour="green")+  # second layer
       xlab("X value")+ylab("PDF")+
       ggtitle("Beta Probability Distribution  Functions")
```

Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Don't start the lines with the `+` sign.

Comment: Looks okay to me. Or was it simply the +'s that was the problem?

Comment: Original question had ggplot with `+` at the beginning of each new line.  The subsequent edits and new plot now appears to be what the OP wanted, right?  In which case, close question?

Comment: I think closing is probably the right thing then. It was just a syntax error, not really worthy of an actual answer...

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate approach to the plotting:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1492) # reproducible

x <- seq(0, 1, .01)

q <- dbeta(x, 2.2, 1.7)
z <- dbeta(x, 3.3, 1.2)

df <- data.frame(x, q, z)
```

Make it into a long data frame so we can use some inherent properties of ggplot2 w/r/t aesthetics.

```
df <- gather(df, func, val, -x)
```

Now, we can use aesthetic mapping vs hard-coding values and doing multiple `geom_line()`s.

```
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=val, group=func))
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(color=func))
```

Tighten up the y axis limits a bit

```
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0))
```

We can actually get a legend now (you could also remove it and manually label the lines with `geom_text()`)

```
gg <- gg + scale_color_manual(name="Beta params", 
                              values=c("#b2182b", "#4393c3"),
                              labels=c("α=2.2, β=1.7", "α=3.3, β=1.2"))
```

Combine multiple label statements into one.

```
gg <- gg + labs(x="x value", y="PDF",
                title="Beta Probability Distribution Functions")
```

Remove some chart junk.

```
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.line=element_line(size=0.15, color="#2b2b2b"))
gg
```

[image]